# How and why should I avoid using "self" in a Ruby method declaration

Tags: ruby, static, self

I was wondering if there is a simplest way to get rid of the "self" when calling a function from another class.
Example, I have here a class that has a function.

```
module Portfolio
    class Main < Sinatra::Base

        def self.create_user(username,password,confirm_pass,fullname)
            @creation_flag = false
            begin
                if password == confirm_pass
                    @creation_flag = User.create(username: username,password: password,full_name: fullname).valid?
                end
            rescue Exception => e
                puts 'Error Occured: '+e.message,""
            end
            return @creation_flag
        end

        def self.

    end
end
```

to use this i need to declare `self.create_user(params goes here)`
is there a way to get rid of the self?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to declare a class method that's the best way to do it. Don't freak out about the syntax, that just means "define class method" in this case.

Comment: oh, i saw a project that has limited use of "self" i don't know if my code is bad or just fine. btw thanks for the opinion.

Comment: Also worth noting that `@creation_flag` is going to persist for the lifespan of that class, which seems really messy. Is that used anywhere else? If not, make it a local variable.

Comment: Since this is Sinatra, can't you just declare a `protected` regular instance method that does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using self, but it bypasses the requirement to create a variable instance of your object, so some die-hard OO programmers would suggest avoiding self for that reason.  If you avoid "self" then you are forced to initialize your class and assign it to a variable name which forces you think of it as a true object, and not just a collection of functions.

Here's an example class to demonstrate how you would call methods with and without "self"

```
class StaticVersusObjectMethod

  def self.class_method
    puts 'Hello, static class method world!'
  end

  def object_method
    puts 'Hello, object-oriented world!'
  end

end

# No need to create an object instance variable if the method was defined with 'self'
StaticVersusObjectMethod.class_method

# You must create an object instance variable to call methods without 'self'
object = StaticVersusObjectMethod.new
object.object_method
```

output:

```
Hello, static class method world!
Hello, object-oriented world!
```

Whether you use self in the declaration should depend on the data you want your method to use.  If the methods will **only** operate on the variables you pass in as parameters, then use 'self'.  On the other hand, don't use 'self' if you want them to act as true object methods.  "True" object methods can operate on the state of the class variables (fields) in the objects which you create and assign to a one or more variable names.

Comment: Thanks sir, im now enlightened.

Comment: By the way my main question is on how to eliminate the self when creating a function.

Comment: John, refer to the last two lines of my example code for the answer.  You can remove the "self" and then you simply simply have to call the method on an object instance of the class.  In your case, create the object with "object = Main.new" and then call "object.create_user" -- do that and you can safely remove the "self" in your declaration.  At this point it should be called a "method" and not a "function".

Comment: The other way is to define an actual "function" and not a method, would be to do it outside of any class (just in the base indentation of your ruby file).  Then you also won't need self, but you won't be able to extend Sinatra::Base, so that's probably not what you want.  If you want to define a method inside of a class without self, then you'll need to create an object instance and assign it to a variable.

Comment: Hi Emery, i just din. i did initialize it in the before do , " @portfolio = Portfolio::Main" Portfolio is a module. i tried it and it gives me a "NoMethodError at /create_user"

Comment: @John_Geliberte you want "def create_user" (no self), then "@portfolio = Portfolio::Main.new" followed by "@portfolio.create_user"